# Is there a function to stream my PiCamera on Webserver

Tags: php, html, apache, raspberry-pi

Is there a reasonable solution to stream a live Video from my PiCamera to an apache2 Server. I want that I can activate the stream using a button on the server and deactivate it the same way. However, I looked up a lot of solutions but didn't find one that belongs to my problem. Maybe someone here knows how to solve it. 
On the apache2 server, I use Html, PHP and CSS. I use the PHP language to configure my other buttons with a python script.

Here you can see my PHP code that I use to activate a script:

```
<html>
<head>
    <form method="post" >
        <input type="submit" value="Schiessen" name="schiessen">
    </form>
<title>MUW</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST["schiessen"]))
    {
        $command = escapeshellcmd("/var/www/html/runMotors.py");
        $output = shell_exec($command);
        echo $output;
    }
    ?>
</body>
```

Here is an example how I want that my server looks like. Most important is that in the middle is a sort of display which shows the live stream. It is very important that you can still use the buttons even if the camera is on. Therefore the camera display should be such as a rectangle in the middle.
[image]

Comment: Have you looked at WebRTC?

Comment: No what is this. Can you use it with apache2?

Comment: https://webrtc.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [flask](https://www.palletsprojects.com/p/flask/) too. That is web framework for python.
for example from the flask home page that is given above:

```py
from flask import Flask, escape, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    name = request.args.get("name", "World")
    return f'Hello, {escape(name)}!'

@app.route('/run_motors')
def run_motors():
    # method calls here.
    return

app.run(host='localhost', port=3000)
```

Your python code will listen to the port that specified by you (5000 is the default one of flask) and when HTTP request comes to the specified route (in this situation the route is '/run_motors') it will make another method calls.

Comment: Could you provide a little more information about your answer please?